# Passing QClipboard to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I am trying to make the clipboard available to some QML code.

Passing the clipboard object seems to work, but then I can't call its methods.

Here's an example of a QClipboard working fine in C++, being passed to QML, and in the debug output it still being a QClipboard object but losing its functions.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QClipboard>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <qqmlcontext.h>
#include <QtQml>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("clipboard", QApplication::clipboard());
    qDebug() << QApplication::clipboard()->text(); // This correctly prints the copied text
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    MouseArea {
        acceptedButtons: Qt.MiddleButton
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log(clipboard)
            console.log(clipboard.getText())
        }
    }
}
```

**qml.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**test.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = app
VERSION = 1.0

QT += qml widgets gui
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,--as-needed

SOURCES += main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`QObject`'s functions need to be slots if you want to call them from QML. `QClipboard` declares no slots, so you can't call its functions directly. You can create a proxy, though:

## `qclipboardproxy.hpp`

```
#ifndef QCLIPBOARDPROXY_HPP
#define QCLIPBOARDPROXY_HPP

#include <QObject>

class QClipboard;

class QClipboardProxy : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ text NOTIFY textChanged)
public:
    explicit QClipboardProxy(QClipboard*);

    QString text() const;

signals:
    void textChanged();

private:
    QClipboard* clipboard;
};

#endif // QCLIPBOARDPROXY_HPP
```

## `qclipboardproxy.cpp`

```
#include "qclipboardproxy.hpp"

#include <QClipboard>

QClipboardProxy::QClipboardProxy(QClipboard* c) : clipboard(c)
{
    connect(c, &QClipboard::dataChanged, this, QClipboardProxy::textChanged)
}

QString QClipboardProxy::text()
{
    return clipboard->text();
}
```

and in

## `main.cpp`

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("clipboard",
    new QClipboardProxy(QGuiApplication::clipboard()));
```

Now you can call:

```
console.log(clipboard.text)
```

or even

```
someProperty: clipboard.text
```

Comment: You could even make text a property on the proxy and get bindings working. I'll propose an edit

Comment: Marking this one as answer because it explains why it doesn't work directly.

Answer (score 11):

Inspired by @krzaq's solution you could even make the proxy a QML instantiable type

```
class ClipboardProxy : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ dataText WRITE setDataText NOTIFY dataChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString selectionText READ selectionText WRITE setSelectionText NOTIFY selectionChanged)
public:
    explicit ClipboardProxy(QObject *parent = 0);

    void setDataText(const QString &text);
    QString dataText() const;

    void setSelectionText(const QString &text);
    QString selectionText() const;

signals:
    void dataChanged();
    void selectionChanged();
};

ClipboardProxy::ClipboardProxy(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    QClipboard *clipboard = QGuiApplication::clipboard();
    connect(clipboard, &QClipboard::dataChanged,
            this, ClipboardProxy::dataChanged);
    connect(clipboard, &QClipboard::selectionChanged,
            this, ClipboardProxy::selectionChanged);
}

void ClipboardProxy::setDataText(const QString &text)
{
    QGuiApplication::clipboard()->setText(text, QClipboard::Clipboard);
}

QString ClipboardProxy::dataText() const
{
    return QGuiApplication::clipboard()->text(QClipboard::Clipboard);
}

void ClipboardProxy::setSelectionText(const QString &text)
{
    QGuiApplication::clipboard()->setText(text, QClipboard::Selection);
}

QString ClipboardProxy::selectionText() const
{
    return QGuiApplication::clipboard()->text(QClipboard::Selection);
}
```

Register as a type in `main()`

```
qmlRegisterType<ClipboardProxy>("Clipboard", 1, 0, "Clipboard");
```

Use as a type in QML

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import Clipboard 1.0

Column {
    Clipboard {
        id: clipboard

        onDataChanged: console.log("Clipboard data changed");
        onSelectionChanged: console.log("Clipboard selection changed");
    }
    Text {
        text: clipboard.text
    }
    TextInput {
        onEditingFinished: clipboard.text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but it seems it cannot compile anymore in Qt5.14; I get a `no matchng member function for call to 'connect'` and also a problem about `reference to non-static ClipboardProxy::dataChanged`. Could you please update it?

Comment: The `connect()` calls are missing the `&` reference symbol before `ClipboardProxy`. Should be, `connect(..., ..., ..., &ClipboardProxy::...);` Otherwise, nice share, thanks!