# How do I modify string from clipboard before paste in a TextFIeld?

Tags: qt, qml, clipboard

The `TextField` type (I'm using QML, but shouldn't matter) provides a [paste()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html#paste-method) method. However, I would like to be able to strip all white space from the clipboard data before the paste happens.

There doesn't seem to be any hooks provided by Qt to do this in a simple fashion. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: call paste() and then change the text in `onTextChaged` event as you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can expose a C++ function that modifies the clipboard data and returns it to QML:

```
class ClipboardModifier : public QObject
{
    // ...

    Q_INVOKABLE QString modifiedClipboardText() const
    {
        QClipboard *clipboard = QGuiApplication::clipboard();
        QString clipboardText = clipboard->text();
        // modify the text...
        return clipboardText;
    }
}
```

Or just make a simple wrapper of QClipboard as shown in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092352/passing-qclipboard-to-qml), and do the modification in QML with JavaScript and then set the text on the text field directly.